# Puppeteer's `page.content()` always in UTF-8 or in page specific charset?

Tags: dom, character-encoding, puppeteer

Does Puppeteer's page.content() return the string always in UTF-8 or in the page-specific charset?

I've seen it uses `document.documentElement.outerHTML`internally ([see source code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/lib/DOMWorld.js#L184)) but not sure how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diving into `outerHTML`'s [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

> Reading the value of outerHTML returns a **DOMString** containing an HTML
>   serialization of the element and its descendants. Setting the value of
>   outerHTML replaces the element and all of its descendants with a new
>   DOM tree constructed by parsing the specified htmlString.

Diving into `DOMString`'s [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString):

> DOMString is a **UTF-16** String. As JavaScript already uses such
>   strings, DOMString is mapped directly to a String.

So it seems the mistery ends here.